Why does glass sphere render differently in Cycles using GPU versus CPU on Apple M3 (Metal) platform?
I modeled a two foot glass sphere with a 1 inch solidify modifier as part of a buoy:

The only lighting source is the Sky Texture node (Nishita sky model). When I render in Cycles using GPUs on an Apple M3 (Metal) platform I end up with these strange linear artifacts:

However when I render in Cycles using CPUs on the same platform I end up with this expected result:

I've tried (a) altering Render settings (bounces, clamping, and caustics), (b) smooth versus auto smooth shading, and (c) recalculating normals without success. Has anyone else experienced this problem and, if so, solved the issue? Could this be a driver issue? Many thanks

In the past with issues like this there's a "high quality normals" checkbox or something like that.

Thank you Allen. I forgot to mention that these are Blender 4.2 viewport renders. High quality normals seem to be limited to the Workbench render engine. Unless I've overlooked something, they don't seem to be available in the Cycles render engine

Is it possible there's a duplicate mesh (perhaps hidden in viewport, easy to forget about)?  There may be a difference in how the two methods handle coplanar surfaces

No, there are is no coincident duplicate mesh. While I was checking I made sure that there were no coincident duplicate faces. And that the normals for the inside and outside faces of the solidified glass ball are pointing in the correct direction. And that there are no transverse faces between the inside and outside faces of the solidified glass ball. While I was at this, I also confirmed that the problem exists in file renders as well as in viewport renders

I systematically deleted every object from the file. I systematically removed all constraints, etc. from the object. The problem persisted. I created a new object with new shaders. The object was created at the origin and looked fine, but on closer inspection there was a hint of artifacts. When I translated the new object next to the original object, the artifacts on the new object intensified. So I now know the intensity of the artifact is scene location specific.

I then suspected that the artifacts may somehow be related to the world lighting and the sky texture node. To test this I first created a 3rd glass sphere object at a lower mesh density. I immediately noticed that while the artifacts were present on the new object, they were at a lower density. So not likely related to world lighting and the sky texture node. To confirm this I copied the objects to a new Blender file with default lighting and the problem persisted.

The problem was resolved in Blender v4.3.0
